# Composable getting bloated with too many callbacks passed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

This is my current composable:

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(
    onPress1: () -> Unit,
    onPress2: () -> Unit,
    onPress3: () -> Unit,
    onPress4: () -> Unit,
    onPress5: () -> Unit,
) {
    Button(onClick = onPress1) { Text(text = "Press 1")}
    Button(onClick = onPress2) { Text(text = "Press 2")}
    Button(onClick = onPress3) { Text(text = "Press 3")}
    Button(onClick = onPress4) { Text(text = "Press 4")}
    Button(onClick = onPress5) { Text(text = "Press 5")}
}
```

Is there a way to reduce this, Similar to how react has useReducer hook with action types and action payload

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use sealed class to create click events that can be reused in different places in your project depending on your need.

```
// Create your different click events
sealed class MyClickEvent {
    object Press1: MyClickEvent()
    object Press2: MyClickEvent()
    object Press3: MyClickEvent()
    object Press4: MyClickEvent()
    // You can create a click event that passes arguments
    data class Press5(val arg: String): MyClickEvent()
}

// Handle each click event ( This function should be inside your view model )
fun onMyClickEvent(event: MyClickEvent) {
    when(event) {
        is MyClickEvent.Press1 -> println("Press1")
        is MyClickEvent.Press2 -> println("Press2")
        is MyClickEvent.Press3 -> println("Press3")
        is MyClickEvent.Press4 -> println("Press4")
        is MyClickEvent.Press5 -> println("Press5: ${event.arg}")
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyMainComposable() {
    MyComposable(
        onMyClickEvent = { event -> onMyClickEvent(event) }
    )
}

// Pass only single lambda for different click events
@Composable
fun MyComposable(
    onMyClickEvent: (event: MyClickEvent) -> Unit,
) {
    Button(onClick = { onMyClickEvent(MyClickEvent.Press1) }) {
        Text(text = "Press 1")
    }
    Button(onClick = { onMyClickEvent(MyClickEvent.Press2) }) {
        Text(text = "Press 2")
    }
    Button(onClick = { onMyClickEvent(MyClickEvent.Press3) }) {
        Text(text = "Press 3")
    }
    Button(onClick = { onMyClickEvent(MyClickEvent.Press4) }) {
        Text(text = "Press 4")
    }
    Button(onClick = { onMyClickEvent(MyClickEvent.Press5(arg = "data")) }) {
        Text(text = "Press 5")
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it bad to have lambda callbacks inside composables?

Comment: @Hyzam no it's not bad, it depends on your needs, but if you have multiple lambda callbacks the code is not going to be readable and maintainable, so to make it more clean we can have one single lambda that take an event as an argument like the example above